# Sum in Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, sum

I have a vector of squared autocorrelationcoefficients and want to perform the Ljung-Box-Test in R.

So far, I've tried different loops, but nothing really worked and my results don't match the ones you get, when you use box.test.. For instance:

```
for(i in 1:20) {

Q<- n*(n+2)*sum((vector_squared [1:i])/(n-i))

}
```

Comment: Maybe initialise a vector `Q` of length `1:20` and then loop values into it using `Q[i] <- ...`

Answer (score 0):

No loop needed here:

```
Q <- n*(n+2)*sum(cumsum(vector_squared)/(n-(1:20)))
```

Also, as correctly pointed out in the comments, you run 20 iterations in the loop and everytime you overwrite what you saved in `Q` in the last iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I usually have a vector which saves the values for every iteration

Comment: Here's a quick rule-of-thumb: `for`-loop are only really needed if an iteration uses what was calculated in a prior iteration.

Comment: Also, if you think this is the answer, please mark it as the answer. ;)